# Pandas: How to use a Numpy function instead of a Lambda function for the same result (since Numpy is faster)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fuzzywuzzy

The command below is giving me the following error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Why and how can I fix it?

```
df['Score'] = np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'], df['Company']))
```

Note - I know that the command below works, but I was hoping to use numpy as I've heard its much faster than lambda:

```
df['Score'] = df['Vendor'].apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x, df['Company']))
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried converting your columns to lists and then using your first attempt like: `df['Score'] = np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'].to_list(), df['Company'].to_list()))`

Comment: Is `fuzz.ratio` from [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/)?

Comment: This fast `numpy` that you've heard about is a set of building blocks (functions/methods) that work with a whole `pandas Series` (column).  Things like addition, mean, products, etc.  Rather basic operations on `arrays`.  You haven't told us anything about `fuzz.ratio`.  It appears to be a function that works with one element of the column, not the whole column (at once).  `apply` applies the function to successive elements of the column.  There isn't a fast numpy magic that does the same thing.

Comment: @luigigi Yup, that worked..Numpy is almost 3 times faster as per the results below. I was wondering if the same could be achieved without converting to list first? That would make it even faster! 


`Lambda: 758 µs ± 8.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Numpy: 253 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

@ Warren Weckesser  yes...that's the fuzzywuzzy library
@ hpaulj I'll bear that in mind, thanks..and yes the fuzz.ratio is from the FuzzyWuzzy library (pip install fuzzywuzzy).

Comment: It looks like `fuzz.ratio` is designed to work with `sequences`, Python lists.  Presumably it also returns a list.  A pandas column/Series is an array, or array-like, and performs different when it comes to comparisons, as the original error shows.  `to_list()` is the fastest way of converting a Series to a list.  You may not need the `np.array()` wrapper.

Comment: A data of a dataframe column, or Series, is (usually) a `numpy` array.  That's why it's possible to add two Series, or scale one.  Operations like that are the fast `numpy` ones that you've heard about.  But if you have iterate (or use code that iterates on a sequence), lists are faster, enough so that often using the `to_list` conversion is worth the extra step.  Throwing arrays or Series into code that is not designed for them (numpy or pandas) may be slower, if it works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should do the same thing as the numpy statement

```
df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x.Vendor, x.Company), axis=1)
```

That is if fuzz.ratio takes a non iterable.

or maybe:

```
np.apply_along_axis(fuzz.ratio, 0, df['Vendor'], df['Company'] )
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to use Numpy since I have 1.2 million records and Numpy is supposed to be much faster.

Comment: @ShadyMBA i added an apply from numpy, not sure if it's faster, but maybe worth a try

Comment: Unfortunately it's giving error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().". Thanks for your efforts anyway :-) others in the post have suggested `df['Score'] = np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'].tolist(), df['Company'].tolist()))` which is working so the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Consider my test dataframe:

```
df =pd.DataFrame([['ACME Factory','ACME Factory Inc.'],['CME Factory Inc.','CMEA Factry'],['ATHMA Inc.','Cypress Hill CO.']],columns=['Vendor','Company'])

df['Score'] = np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'].values[0],df['Company'].values[0]))

        Vendor            Company  Score
0      ACME Factory  ACME Factory Inc.          83
1      CME Factory Inc.        CMEA Factry      83
2        ATHMA Inc.   Cypress Hill CO.          83
```

Obviously my score calculation is wrong, I believe it is due to the problems I had while installing python-Levenshtein, 
which is a dependence for the proper work of fuzzywuzzy library. But I could get rid off the:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

That I could successfully reproduce.

[image]

What I don't know is how will be the performance for all these cast conversions (.values[0])
With .values you get only the data from the datframe, but it comes inside of a list and using the [0] you get the string out of the list.

Tell me if it works for you.

ShadyMBA suggestion:
[image]

Comment: Careful! I think your code leads to wrong results. You are getting 83 across the entire column because in each row it is comparing ['ACME Factory','ACME Factory Inc.'], not the companies related to that row. To test it I've used:

`df =pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],['CME Factory Inc.','CMEA Factry'],['ATHMA Inc.','Cypress Hill CO.']],columns=['Vendor','Company'])
df['Score'] = np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'].values[0],df['Company'].values[0]))
`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I didn't read the documentation of the fuzzywuzzy, my mistake. I've thought the funny result was related to the fail during python-Levenshtein installation. Anyway, I've tried to reproduce your problem
with the single line of code you provided and was able to find out a solution to the issue you've asked about in your question. 
I also tried the dataframe you suggested and it was no good. I've printed the code execution and the output in my answer, in "shayMBA suggestion".

Comment: You're very welcome :-) you said "and was able to find out a solution to the issue you've asked about in your question"...so what was the solution? Anyway please don't spend too much time on it as someone provided this solution that works: `np.array(fuzz.ratio(df['Vendor'].tolist(), df['Company'].tolist()))`

Comment: ShadyMBA, I've believed that the problem was the " ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."